# Add a new file in an existing solution

Tags: visual-studio

I don't know how to add a new file in an existing project solution in Visual studio. Can you please help me.

I want to add the file into the existing solution so that I can run the application well without missing any file.

Comment: What have you tried? It's as simple as using the "File -> Add..." menu or right-clicking a node in the solution explorer and click "Add..." in the context menu. Literally how it's done in almost every other piece of software in the world.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of information you can refer to the official documentation under 
[Add files to a solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-solutions-and-projects?view=vs-2022#add-files-to-a-solution)

> If you have a file that applies to multiple projects, such as a readme file for the solution, or other files that logically belong at the solution level rather than under a specific project, then you can add them to the solution itself. To add an item to a solution, **on the context (right-click) menu of the solution node in Solution Explorer, select Add > New Item, or Add > Existing Item**.